# 403 forbidden on bower components

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, apache2, bower, http-status-code-403

I am use apache with virtual host as my server. I also use yeoman to generate angular app template. For some reason, when I launch my site, I can see the index page but the console gave me 403 forbidden errors all on bower components like bootstrap, angular.js...etc. I am not sure what I did wrong. Can someone help? Thanks!

my V-host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myname@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/John/testproject/app"
    ServerName testproject.localhost
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testproject-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testproject-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/John/testproject/app">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My project structure.

```
testproject
   app 
       bower_components <-symlink
   bower_components
       angular     <----403 error
       bootstrap   <----403 error
       ...etc
   Gruntfile.js
   Bower.json
```

My url on the browser

```
testproject.localhost
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your project under /var/www/ directory as /User directory is not accessible to apache2 and after moving folder check permission 
and set permission to 777

```
sudo chmod -r 755 folder_path
```

if still don't work set it to

```
sudo chmod -r 777 folder path
```

and restart apache2. Also don't forget to change path in apache2 config file.